# Certificate for WCF message security

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I am developing a WCF service and Windows forms client and using message security (authenticate with user name, password, and certificate (public and private key) at server, server public key at client). Verified with temporary certificate using makecert.

Now I need to publish my application in GoDaddy.

Can I use the SSL Certificate from GoDaddy for WCF message security (WS-Security) or do we need to buy a different type of certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it means you would have to have the GoDaddy SSL certificate installed on every client. Normally you would not expect the SSL certificate itself to be installed on a client, instead you would have a certificate from somewhere higher in the certificate issuer chain installed and verify the GoDaddy SSL certificate by chaining.

However, if you are able to distribute the GoDaddy cert (minus the private key, obviously) with your client application then you should be able to do it. Certificates generally have Purpose, which is the intended use of them. I imagine your GoDaddy certificate would have an intended use of SSL only, but I don't think that really matters.

Comment: Sorry to say, Iam still in confused as iam new to SSL or WCF certification , but so far I could able to use certificate with makecert using sample server and client ( manually installed on server and client)

Comment: But when using the WinForms application, the user should still have to provide credentials, yes? Otherwise they would be able to use the application without being authenticated (e.g. if there were registered, downloaded the app and then got unregistered). The answer to your question is yes, you can do this. I think this link will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752233.aspx